# Implementing Real-Time Calculation of Synthetic Variables with MongoDB

Tags: reactjs, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, iot

Hello Stack Overflow community,

I'm seeking advice on the implementation of real-time calculation of synthetic variables from two existing variables stored in MongoDB, with React frontend integration. Below is a detailed overview of my current architecture and specific challenges:

**Collections Schema:-**

**Devices Collection:**

- Stores information about different datasources.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "name": "Datasource Name",
  "description": "Description of the datasource"
}
```

**Variables Collection:**

- Stores information about variables, including their names,
  descriptions, and units of measurement.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "name": "Variable Name",
  "deviceId":ObjectId("...")  //Reference to the device
}
```

**Values (Time Series) Collection:**

- Stores time-stamped values for variables associated with variables
  belonging to a datasource.

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("..."),
  "ts": ISODate("..."),           // Timestamp of the value
  "val": 123.45,                   // Actual value
  "metafield": {
    "variableId": ObjectId("..."),
  }
}
```

**Backend Technology:**
The backend is implemented using Node.js.

**Problem:**

Consider a scenario where data from a device is captured (every **10 seconds**) and stored with multiple variables. For instance:

```
{
  "power-1": 98.2,
  "power-2": 23.5,
  "voltage-1": 56.77,
  "voltage-2": 122.56,
  "frequency-1": 8,
  "frequency-2": 54.7
}
```

Users should be able to select two variables (e.g., **power-1** and **power-2**) and define an arithmetic operation (e.g., **((power-1 + power-2) * 100) / 1000)**. The result, referred to as a synthetic variable (e.g., **power**), should be calculated in real-time and displayed in real-time to the user whenever the user logs in.

**Specific Questions:**

1. **Creation of Synthetic Variables:** How can I efficiently calculate synthetic variables in real-time from two existing variables  based on user selection within the React frontend?
2. **React Frontend Integration:** What are the best practices for integrating the calculated synthetic variables with a React frontend? How can I handle real-time updates and ensure a responsive user interface?
3. **Handling Dynamic Variable Changes:** Given the dynamic nature of variables associated with datasources, how should I handle changes in the Variables collection, and how can I ensure that these changes are reflected appropriately in the calculated synthetic variables?

I appreciate any insights, best practices, or sample code snippets that the community can provide. Thank you in advance for your valuable input!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @Quassnoi , I've only inserted data into the DB using a node consumer reading from Kinesis Data Streams. I've got no clue where to start from to implement the functionality i mentioned.

Comment: I suggest that you split your problem into bite-sized chunks and focus on one at a time. The way this question is written, it's not suitable for the site.